# Vibration of a continuous uniform chain and the normal modes

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, functional-derivatives, normal-modes

The question is:

A vertically hanged chain with the upper end attached to a fixed point. I try to find the normal modes under the small $\theta$ condition.
Consider the mass $\mathrm{d}m$ with distance $s$ away from the fixed point(along the direction of the chain), the coordinate is:

$x=\int_{0}^{s}\sin{\theta}\ \mathrm{d}s=\int_{0}^{s}\theta\ \mathrm{d}s$, and $y=\int_{0}^{s}(1-\frac{\theta^{2}}{2})\mathrm{d}s$.

Take $s=zL$, where $L$ is the total length of the chain, and $0<z<1$. $\omega_{0}^{2}=\frac{g}{L}$. $\theta$ as the generalized coordinate is the function of z and t, $\theta(z,t)$.

Hence I got the Lagrangian of the whole chain:
\begin{equation}
L=\frac{1}{2}\rho L^{3}\int_{0}^{1}\left[(\int_{0}^{z}\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}\mathrm{d}\zeta)^{2}-\omega_{0}^{2}(\int_{0}^{z}\theta^{2}\mathrm{d}\zeta)\right]\mathrm{d}z
\end{equation}

Through Lagrangian the equation of motion should directly lead to the normal modes of the oscillation. But I am now having trouble with the derivatives of Lagrangian to obtain the equation of motion, specifically the operation such as $\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot\theta}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}$, as the Lagrangian comes in the form of integrals with variable bounds $z$.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me some inspiration of the simple calculus operation...